# Spring Data Mongodb Connection Pool Concurrent Requests Limit

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I want to know how spring data mongodb connection pool works.

Imagine a spring boot rest api server connected to
mongodb via spring data mongodb. If the default connection pool size is 100,
does it mean that only 100 simultaneous curl requests can be served ? what happens if there is 200 simultaneous requests?

How do i know the maximum pool size for a given server? for example, if i have a server with 8 GB of RAM, what is the maximum pool size i can set? what happens if i set pool size to like 1million and my server cannot handle 1 million mongodb pool size

Answer (score 0):

`Mongodb` Connection pool will be managed by `MongoDB` server based on parameters you passed to it.

By default `maxPoolSize` is set to `100`

To modify it you can pass values like this

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/?connectTimeoutMS=30000&minPoolSize=0&maxPoolSize=50
```

[Refer doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-connection-options) for more detail

> what happens if there is 200 simultaneous requests?

In general when the pool reaches this size, and no idle connections are available, calls to `getConnection()` will block for up to `connectionTimeout` milliseconds before timing out.

Comment: how do i know the maximum pool size for a given server? for example, if i have a server with 8 GB of RAM, what is the maximum pool size i can set? what happens if i set pool size to like 1million and my server cannot handle 1 million mongodb pool size?

Comment: There is no direct answer for this.  This might help   https://dzone.com/articles/optimum-database-connection-pool-size

Comment: yeah if i only have 1 api server that connects to db, the article would make sense, but what if i have multiple api servers connecting to the same mongodb? i still want to know the max no of connections to my 8gb ram mongodb server